# Enumerating Cartesian product while minimizing repetition

Tags: algorithm, math, enumeration, discrete-mathematics, cartesian-product

Given two sets, e.g.:

```
{A B C}, {1 2 3 4 5 6}
```

I want to generate the Cartesian product in an order that puts as much space as possible between equal elements. For example, `[A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, B1…]` is no good because all the `A`s are next to each other. An acceptable solution would be going "down the diagonals" and then every time it wraps offsetting by one, e.g.:

```
[A1, B2, C3, A4, B5, C6, A2, B3, C4, A5, B6, C1, A3…]
```

Expressed visually:

```
|   | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 2 |   | 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3 |   |   | 3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   | 4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 5 |   |   |   |   | 5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 6 |   |   |   |   |   | 6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   | 7 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 9 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 10|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 11|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 12|   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 13|   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 14|   |   |   |   |
| 5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 15|   |   |   |
| 6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 16|   |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 17|   |
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 18|
```

or, equivalently but without repeating the rows/columns:

```
|   | A  | B  | C  |
|---|----|----|----|
| 1 | 1  | 17 | 15 |
| 2 | 4  | 2  | 18 |
| 3 | 7  | 5  | 3  |
| 4 | 10 | 8  | 6  |
| 5 | 13 | 11 | 9  |
| 6 | 16 | 14 | 12 |
```

I imagine there are other solutions too, but that's the one I found easiest to think about. But I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to express it generically—it's a convenient thing that the cardinality of the two sets are multiples of each other, but I want the algorithm to do The Right Thing for sets of, say, size 5 and 7. Or size 12 and 69 (that's a real example!).

Are there any established algorithms for this? I keep getting distracted thinking of how rational numbers are mapped onto the set of natural numbers (to prove that they're countable), but the path it takes through ℕ×ℕ doesn't work for this case.

It so happens the application is being written in Ruby, but I don't care about the language. Pseudocode, Ruby, Python, Java, Clojure, Javascript, CL, a paragraph in English—choose your favorite.

---

Proof-of-concept solution in Python (soon to be ported to Ruby and hooked up with Rails):

```
import sys

letters = sys.argv[1]
MAX_NUM = 6

letter_pos = 0
for i in xrange(MAX_NUM):
    for j in xrange(len(letters)):
        num = ((i + j) % MAX_NUM) + 1
        symbol = letters[letter_pos % len(letters)]
        print "[%s %s]"%(symbol, num)
        letter_pos += 1
```

Comment: If the cardinalities are not multiples all that happens is that it takes longer to wrap - e.g. A1 B2 C3 D1 A2 B3 C1 D2 A3 B1 C2 D3. If the two numbers are coprime they don't wrap until you have covered the whole set. So all you need to do is wait until the wrap happens and then find a symbol that has not been covered yet.

Comment: This sounds a lot like linear algebra homework. I think you are explaining the problem wrong. Take a step back and read your course material. It should be obvious what the problem is getting at.

Comment: It's not homework. The application is a workout app in Rails I'm doing as a hobby project; the basic idea is that if you have six types of ab exercise that can each be done straight, to the left, or to the right there are 18 total exercises but you don't want to do all of them every day and if you're only doing 5 a day you don't want them to all be on the same side of the body. So the app will figure out all the combinations and then present a sensible order to do them in. I just didn't want to pollute that matter with DB schema and such—my core question is about the algorithm.

Comment: @tsm: My most humble apologies! I was reading it as graphics problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String letters = "ABC";
int MAX_NUM = 6;

int letterPos = 0;
for (int i=0; i < MAX_NUM; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < MAX_NUM; ++j) {
        int num = ((i + j) % MAX_NUM) + 1;
        char symbol = letters.charAt(letterPos % letters.length);
        String output = symbol + "" + num;
        ++letterPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should one of your `for` conditions be different though? This'll always generate 36 combinations, whereas `|{ABC} x {123456}|` is of course 18 and I'd like to replace `ABC` with, for example, `ABCDEFGH` at some point

Comment: Ah, I understand and have it working. You can see what I'm using (well, in Python…eventually it'll be in Ruby) in the OP.

Comment: @tsm I coded to match the algorithm you gave.  Feel free to make an edit if you wish.

Comment: It's fine—I just needed to make it more generic. All it is is changing one of the `MAX_NUM`s to `letters.length`.

Answer (score 2):

What about using something fractal/recursive? This implementation divides a rectangular range into four quadrants then yields points from each quadrant. This means that neighboring points in the sequence differ at least by quadrant.

```
#python3

import sys
import itertools

def interleave(*iters):
  for elements in itertools.zip_longest(*iters):
    for element in elements:
      if element != None:
        yield element

def scramblerange(begin, end):
  width = end - begin

  if width == 1:
    yield begin

  else:
    first = scramblerange(begin, int(begin + width/2))
    second = scramblerange(int(begin + width/2), end)
    yield from interleave(first, second)

def scramblerectrange(top=0, left=0, bottom=1, right=1, width=None, height=None):
  if width != None and height != None:
    yield from scramblerectrange(bottom=height, right=width)
    raise StopIteration

  if right - left == 1:
    if bottom - top == 1:
      yield (left, top)

    else:
      for y in scramblerange(top, bottom):
        yield (left, y)

  else:
    if bottom - top == 1:
      for x in scramblerange(left, right):
        yield (x, top)

    else:
      halfx = int(left + (right - left)/2)
      halfy = int(top + (bottom - top)/2)

      quadrants = [
        scramblerectrange(top=top, left=left, bottom=halfy, right=halfx),
        reversed(list(scramblerectrange(top=top, left=halfx, bottom=halfy, right=right))),
        scramblerectrange(top=halfy, left=left, bottom=bottom, right=halfx),
        reversed(list(scramblerectrange(top=halfy, left=halfx, bottom=bottom, right=right)))
      ]

      yield from interleave(*quadrants)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  output = []

  indices = dict()
  for i, pt in enumerate(scramblerectrange(width=11, height=5)):
    indices[pt] = i
    x, y = pt
    output.append(letters[x] + str(y))

  table = [[indices[x,y] for x in range(11)] for y in range(5)]

  print(', '.join(output))
  print()
  pad = lambda i: ' ' * (2 - len(str(i))) + str(i)
  header = '  |' + ' '.join(map(pad, letters[:11]))
  print(header)
  print('-' * len(header))
  for y, row in enumerate(table):
    print(pad(y)+'|', ' '.join(map(pad, row)))
```

Outputs:

```
a0, i1, a2, i3, e0, h1, e2, g4, a1, i0, a3, k3, e1,
h0, d4, g3, b0, j1, b2, i4, d0, g1, d2, h4, b1, j0,
b3, k4, d1, g0, d3, f4, c0, k1, c2, i2, c1, f1, a4,
h2, k0, e4, j3, f0, b4, h3, c4, j2, e3, g2, c3, j4,
f3, k2, f2

  | a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k
-----------------------------------
 0|  0 16 32 20  4 43 29 13  9 25 40
 1|  8 24 36 28 12 37 21  5  1 17 33
 2|  2 18 34 22  6 54 49 39 35 47 53
 3| 10 26 50 30 48 52 15 45  3 42 11
 4| 38 44 46 14 41 31  7 23 19 51 27
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sets X and Y are sizes m and n, and Xi is the index of the element from X that's in the ith pair in your Cartesian product (and similar for Y), then

```
Xi = i mod n;
Yi = (i mod n + i div n) mod m;
```

You could get your diagonals a little more spread out by filling out your matrix like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m*n; i++) {
  int xi = i % n;
  int yi = i % m;
  while (matrix[yi][xi] != 0) {
    yi = (yi+1) % m;
  }
  matrix[yi][xi] = i+1;
}
```